# Increment counter in a foreach loop depending on condition result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I have an array being generated from a mysql query which looks like the following. They key is the `order_id` value.

**orders array**

```
Array
(
    [2646] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2646
        )

    [2647] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2647
        )

    [2650] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2650
        )

    [2658] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2658
        )

)
```

I am looking at adding items to each row of the array with items from another array which looks like.

**order_items array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2646
            [prod_code] => 2811
            [order_qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2646
            [prod_code] => 2812A
            [order_qty] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2647
            [prod_code] => 2812A
            [order_qty] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2647
            [prod_code] => 2810
            [order_qty] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2650
            [prod_code] => 2906
            [order_qty] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2650
            [prod_code] => 2908
            [order_qty] => 6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2650
            [prod_code] => 2909
            [order_qty] => 3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2650
            [prod_code] => 2913
            [order_qty] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2658
            [prod_code] => 2880
            [order_qty] => 3
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2658
            [prod_code] => 2881
            [order_qty] => 3
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2658
            [prod_code] => 2882
            [order_qty] => 1
        )

)
```

What i am having trouble working out it how to loop over the `order_items` array and insert the `prod_code` and `order_qty` values into the `order` array where the `order_id` values match. Here is what i have so far.

```
// create orders array - key by order_id
while ($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($order_rows)) {
    $orders[$order['order_id']] = $order;
}

// create the order_items array
while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_rows)) {
    $order_items[] = $item;
}

// update orders array with ordered items
$item_index = 1;
foreach ($order_items as $key => $value) {

    // get the order id
    $item_order_id = $value['order_id'];

    // update orders array with ordered items grouped by order_id
    if ($item_order_id == $orders[$item_order_id]['order_id']) {
        $orders[$item_order_id]['prod_code_'.$item_index] = $value['prod_code'];
        $orders[$item_order_id]['order_qty_'.$item_index] = $value['order_qty'];

        // same order id so increment the counter
        $item_index++;

    } else {

        // new order id start at 1
        $item_index = 1;
    }

}
```

My problem is that the counter does not reset back to 1 when we are looking at a new `item_order_id`.

The output i am trying to achieve for my array is something like this.

**desired orders array output**

```
Array
(
    [2646] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2646
            [prod_code_1] => 2811
            [order_qty_1] => 1
            [prod_code_2] => 2812A
            [order_qty_2] => 3
        )

    [2647] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2647
            [prod_code_1] => 2812A
            [order_qty_1] => 2
            [prod_code_2] => 2810
            [order_qty_2] => 2
        )

    [2650] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2650
            [prod_code_1] => 2906
            [order_qty_1] => 1
            [prod_code_2] => 2908
            [order_qty_2] => 6
            [prod_code_3] => 2909
            [order_qty_3] => 3
            [prod_code_4] => 2913
            [order_qty_4] => 1
        )

    [2658] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 2658
            [prod_code_1] => 2880
            [order_qty_1] => 3
            [prod_code_2] => 2881
            [order_qty_2] => 3
            [prod_code_3] => 2882
            [order_qty_3] => 1
        )

)
```

Any feedback or assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[prod_code_1]`, `[prod_code_2]`.... ewwww.... why not `[prod_code] => array(2906, 2908, 2909, 2913)`?

Comment: The final array will be saved to a text file (csv) and this is the format which the third party app requires the data to be structured.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two passes:

1. Aggregate order items by order id
2. Construct final output

#### First pass

```
// create the order_items array
while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_rows)) {
    $order_items[$item['order_id']][] = $item;
}
```

#### Second pass

```
foreach($order_items as $order_id => $order_items) {
    $record = ['order_id' => $order_id];
    // add order items
    foreach($order_items as $index => $order_item) {
        foreach ($order_item as $attribute_name => $attribute_value) {
            $key = sprintf('%s_%d', $attribute_name, $index + 1);
            $record[$key] = $attribute_value;
        }
    }
    // generate csv row with record here
}
```